# HashCode method for objects in many-to-many relationship when autobinding

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have two objects with many-to-many relationship. An article can be in different sections and a section can have many articles.

```
class Article {
    String title
    static belongsTo = Section
    Set<Section> sectionSet = [] as Set

    static hasMany = [
           sectionSet: Section
    ]
}

class Section {
    String title
    String uniqueUrl   // an unique identifier for the section

    List<Article> articleList = []
    static hasMany = [
            articleList: Article
    ]

    static mapping = {
        uniqueUrl(unique: true)
    }

    boolean equals(o) {
        if (this.is(o)) return true
        if (getClass() != o.class) return false

        Section section = (Section) o

        if (uniqueUrl != section.uniqueUrl) return false

        return true
    }

    int hashCode() {
        return uniqueUrl.hashCode()
    }

}
```

Now I want create a new article by binding a parameter from a controller like this:

```
params = [title: "testArticle", "sectionSet[0].id": "1"] // a section with ID=1 exists in database
Article article = new Article(params) // NullPointerException here because I add this article into the section and uniqueUrl for calculating hashCode() is null
```

I encountered the problem with hashCode because the section with ID 1 is not loaded from db and therefore its fields are all null. The example works fine if I don't override the equals and hashCode, but I guess I have to override if I want to use objects in a set...

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use any Set if you want to bind with index of List sectionSet[0].id !!! Only List!!!
2. Use command Object.
3. Add Article should be follow:

   def selectedSections = Section.findAll(params.list('section.id'));

   def article = new Article(params)

   selectedSections.each{ it.addToArticleList(article).save(true) }

Comment: Thx. I used your 3rd advice and it works! As to your 1st advice, IMO it's perfectly ok to bind Set like this. You just have to know that those indexes can't be relied on. It's also in the documentation of Grails: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding